# How to get product availability with product id in magento?

Tags: magento

Is it possible to get product availability by passing a product ID to the Magento system?

Comment: Got the answer...!!!


  $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $_product = $model->load($product_id); 

  $stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();

This will fetch the qty of a product..

Comment: You can put it in an answer and format the code properly. It will probably help others.

Comment: I am being new to Stackoverflow.. i can put answer only after 24 hrs.. thats why posted in comments..

Comment: Alright, wasn't aware of that. I'll do it for you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To fetch the quantity (in stock) for any given product

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
$_product = $model->load($product_id); 
$stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                ->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
```

Comment: With all due respect for a working answer - The top two lines of this answer are very wasteful. The `$product_id` could have been used directly on the stock_item model's `loadByProduct()` method. The answer by `Anatoly A. Kazantsev` has far superior performance. This answer abuses server resources by loading the full product model unnecessarily.

Answer (score 18):

You can get stock info (`Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` class) by product's ID without loading whole product data (at least in Magento 1.7)

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
               ->loadByProduct($productId);
```

And then you can use `getQty()` and other methods on `$stockItem` object to get required info. You can find them in the source file for the class

Answer (score 6):

For some types of products zero qty of product doesn't mean it's out of stock. Then you can use

```
 $stockStatus = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item') 
                     ->loadByProduct($product)
                     ->getIsInStock();
```

For collection one of the ways is

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 



        if (! Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->isShowOutOfStock()) {
           Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Magento 1.7

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$qty = $product->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

Should work too